# how can I build formio.js library locally

Tags: angular, formio

I have downloaded formIo.js library project from **https://github.com/formio/formio.js**.

Now I want to build it locally and want to use it in my some other project instead of installing it from NPM.

Please guide me step by step process to create its build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gulp build task that can be invoked to run through the build process.

```
i.e gulp build
```